# Size of GLSL uniform?

Tags: glsl, shader

I can't seem to find out how to get the size, in scalars, (or bytes) of a uniform in GLSL.

Currently I call glGetActiveUniform as I enumerate all my shader constants, but the size parameter it returns is an array size, not a variable size.

Is there a function to get the data size? Or a function that maps the ConstantType to its size?

Here's my code, for completeness:

```
char ConstantName[ 128 ];
GLint ConstantArraySize;
GLenum ConstantType;
glGetActiveUniform( Program, ConstantIndex, 128, nullptr, &ConstantArraySize, &ConstantType, ConstantName );
```

Comment: Do you know the type of uniform you're looking at? mat4x4? vec3? If you do then you should be able to provide the sizes your self. I think there's information on this in the GLSL spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the size of all data types in OpenGL are standardized. floats and ints are 32 bits, doubles are 64. Using the information given to you by `glGetActiveUniform()`, you can work out the size of a uniform variable yourself. Having a GL function to do that for you would be superfluous.

Comment: You say superfluous, I say convenient :) I know I can write a big switch statement for this based on the type, I was just wondering if there was some "better" built-in method. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Well, that's how standards committees tend to see things. Look at C++! There are so many things they could add to that to make it more convenient to use.

Comment: From https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_%28GLSL%29#Vectors: "Warning: The specific sizes and formats for integers and floats in GLSL are only for GLSL 1.30 and above. Lower versions of GLSL may not use these exact specifications."

Answer (score 3):

The size of a uniform in GLSL is only relevant if that uniform is stored in a uniform block. For non-block uniforms, you don't care; you upload them with `glUniform*` and let OpenGL handle any conversions.

For uniform block members, each uniform of basic type has a specific byte size. Individual integers and floats are 32-bits in size. Vectors of those types are that size * the number of components. Matrices are more complex; they are stored as column/row (you can pick) vectors. The stride between columns/rows is[something you have to query](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Program_Introspection#Uniforms_and_blocks), with [`glGetActiveUniformsiv`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetActiveUniforms) (note the "s").

Unless you use std140 layout of course, in which case the matrix stride is always 4 * the number of the basic component type. So in std140 layout, a `mat4x2`, stored column-major, represents 4 column vectors of `vec2`s, but the stride between individual column vectors is 4 * sizeof(float), not 2 * sizeof(float). So there's 2 floats worth of padding.

In short, there's no reason to care. If it's a non-block uniform, the size is irrelevant. If it's a uniform block uniform, then you should be using std140 layout anyway and thus can compute it a priori.

Comment: My shader system stores the constants locally, so they can be set even when the shader program isn't bound. This also allows me to test if they've changed to avoid redundant API calls. Maybe this is a bad idea.. but it seemed like a good one in my head.. thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Hybrid: That doesn't explain why you need the *byte size*.

Comment: How can i store my constants locally unless I know how big they are?

Comment: @Hybrid: How big they are to *you* has nothing to do with how big they are to the OpenGL internal shader representation. `glUniformiv` takes `GLint`s. `glUniformfv` takes `GLfloat`s. `glUniformuiv` takes `GLuint`s. That's all of the sizing information you need.